# replace html content with other using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have html structure like below

```
<div class="block-compose">
<button class="icon icon-smiley btn-emoji"></button>
<div tabindex="-1" class="input-container">
    <div class="input-emoji">
        <div class="input-placeholder" style="display: none;">Type a message</div>
        <div dir="auto" spellcheck="true" data-tab="1" contenteditable="true" class="input">how r u</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ptt-container"><span><button class="icon btn-icon icon-ptt"></button></span></div></div>
```

now i want to replace

```
<div class="ptt-container"><span><button class="icon btn-icon icon-ptt"></button></span></div>
```

by

```
<button class="icon btn-icon icon-send send-container"></button>
```

i am facing bit difficult do via javascript i am able to do it via jquery .

please help me with this

Comment: Just curious why you need to do this? What purpose does the <div> and <span> surrounding the button serve? Can you not just replace the button with your new button and leave the div and span?

Comment: i am new and just learning how it can be done in javascrip only

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `replaceChild` from the parent:-

```js
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('ptt-container')[0];
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.className = 'icon btn-icon icon-send send-container';

container.parentElement.replaceChild(button, container);
```

```html
<div class="block-compose">
  <button class="icon icon-smiley btn-emoji"></button>
  <div tabindex="-1" class="input-container">
    <div class="input-emoji">
      <div class="input-placeholder" style="display: none;">Type a message</div>
      <div dir="auto" spellcheck="true" data-tab="1" contenteditable="true" class="input">how r u</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ptt-container"><span><button class="icon btn-icon icon-ptt"></button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW I think it would be useful for knowledge's sake to show also the `*.querySelector()` approach that will resolve in a direct DOM object without the need to look for the first element of a single item array (if we're talking about a single instance of the object, of course). As opposite, even an intro to the `*.querySelectorAll()` would be useful. However it depends all on the OP's needs and cross-browser requirements. :)